# What is the state of the art/best practice for implementing ruby rake test for gems?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rubygems, rake

I would like some guidance as to the state of the art in writing ruby tests and invoking them from rake for a gem. I have been reading on the internets and reviewing code but have seen many ways to do it. What is the leading method to implement unit tests using rake?

note : I am using ruby-1.9.2-p290 with rvm and newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few equally popular ruby libraries that you can use to test your gem.
[Test Unit](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) and [Rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) are the more popular choices.

It doesn't really matter which testing library you go for, so long as it's easy to setup and use, so pick whichever best suits you.

It's common practise to have the `rake` command without any arguments run the test suite for your gem. You can add a 'default' task in your Rakefile to achieve this, something like:

```
task :default => [:test]
# or
task :default => [:spec]
```

Also be sure to include any setup required to get your test suite going in the README.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Now what about pulling in all the subtests? I have seen code with ```sh "ruby test/basic_test.rb"``` which i found quite confusing. Now I am using something like this ```desc 'Run tests (default)'
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/*_test.rb']
  t.ruby_opts = ['-Itest']
  t.ruby_opts << '-rubygems' if defined? Gem
end``` I assume it is ok?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean about subtests, perhaps you can elaborate? If you're talking about tests for other gems then you shouldn't be testing them, the gem author should be doing that for you. That default rake task looks good :)

Comment: I mean the individual test cases, the .t files how to connect them to the rake file. how does it know which ones to execute.